# Launching specific page of worklight application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How to launch a specific page of hybrid worklight application on clicking a link in email?

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through all the steps involved, but yes, you can do this.

**Step 1**

1. Create a Worklight application using, for example, jQuery Mobile to handle the multiple pages

**Step 2**

2. If the app is intended for Android, you will need to modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` file with an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) in order to associate the app with an action and a custom URL scheme

   - You can read more about this by googling for "opening android application using a custom URL scheme", for example
3. If the app is intended for iOS, you will need to modify the `<app-name->info.plist` file with a custom URL scheme

   - You can probably follow this guide: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

**Step 3**

4. Once you get the app to open from an external link, you need to handle the parameters. You'll want this since you want to open a specific page. This is also mentioned for iOS in the above link, and you'll need to further google this for Android

**Step 4**

5. Once you've obtained the parameter, you can use the [Send Action to JavaScript from Native API for iOS and Andriod in Worklight](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_sending_actions_native_to_js.html?lang=en) in order to pass a command to JavaScript, telling the web code to do some changePage function that will load the specific page